# could not call certain variables

Tags: java

```
//Calculating term frequency
    System.out.println("The number of files is this folder is : " + numDoc);

    System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scan.nextLine();

    String[] array = word.split(" ");
    int filename = 11;
    String[] fileName = new String[filename];
    int a = 0;

    for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
        try {
            System.out.println("The word inputted is " + word);
            File file = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc" + a
                            + ".txt");
            System.out.println(" _________________");

            System.out.print("| File = abc" + a + ".txt | \t\t \n");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                int totalCount = 0;
                int wordCount = 0;

                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                {
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        totalCount++;
                        if (s.next().equals(array[i]))
                            wordCount++;

                    }

                    System.out.print(array[i] + " ---> Word count =  "
                            + "\t\t " + "|" + wordCount + "|");
                    System.out.print("  Total count = " + "\t\t " + "|"
                            + totalCount + "|");
                    System.out.printf("  Term Frequency =  | %8.4f |",
                            (double) wordCount / totalCount);

                    System.out.println("\t ");

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File is not found");

        }

    }
// Count inverse document frequency

    System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word2 = scan2.nextLine();
    String[] array2 = word2.split(" ");

    for (int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {
        int numofDoc = 0;



        for (int i = 0; i < filename; i++) {

            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc"
                                + i + ".txt"));

                int matchedWord = 0;

                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(in);

                {

                    while (s2.hasNext()) {
                        if (s2.next().equals(array2[b]))
                            matchedWord++;
                    }

                }
                if (matchedWord > 0)
                    numofDoc++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> This number of files that contain the term  " +  numofDoc);
        double inverseTF = Math.log10 ( (float)numDoc/ numofDoc );
        System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> IDF " +  inverseTF);
        double TFIDF = ((double) wordCount / totalCount)) * inverseTF);
    }

}
```

I could not calculate the TFIDF because the compiler says that `wordCount` does not initialize to a variable. I could not call it from above code. Any guidance ? Thank you.

Comment: why is there an open bracket after `Scanner s = new Scanner(file);` creating a code block?  Also, what line of code is the compiler giving you the error on?

Comment: double TFIDF = ((double) wordCount / totalCount)) * inverseTF);

this line of code give me error. I know i initialize the variable inside a block and now i attempting to use it outside of the block. Does it mean that i cannot use the value of wordCOunt anymore ?

Answer (score 4):

`wordCount` is a local variable that is declared in `for` loop. Once the loop is over, it goes out of scope and cannot be used. Same is the problem with `totalCount` too. Place it before `for` loop, instead;

```
int wordCount = 0;
int totalCount = 0;
for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int totalCount = 0;
            int wordCount = 0;
```

This defines totalCount and wordCount in the scope of that for-loop. You are trying to access these variables from outside the for-loop (down below). What you can do is more these declarations to the top, e.g. where you write `String word = scan.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you initilialize the wordCount varibale in the location unreachbale to
`double TFIDF = ((double) wordCount / totalCount)) * inverseTF);`

Answer (score 0):

`wordCount` is defined inside of your for loop and you're trying to access the variable outside of the said loop, this can't work.

You must move the variable definition somewhere else, for example at the beginning of your method.

Comment: what if the variable moved will affect the results ?